# How to convert a string to pandas datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a column in my pandas data frame which is `string` and want to convert it to pandas `date` so that I will be able to sort

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['202101', '202212']})
dat['col'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

However this generates error. Could you please help to find the correct way to perform this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code should work.

```
dat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dat['col'], format= "%Y%m")
dat['date'] = dat['date'].dt.to_period('M')
dat.sort_values(by = 'date')
```

If you want to replace the sorted dataframe add in brackets inplace = True.
Your code didn't work because your wrong format to date. If you would have date in format for example 20210131 yyyy-mm-dd. This code would be enought.

```
dat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dat['col'], format= "%Y%m%d")
```